# How do you find the standard deviation of a dataset over a certain period?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R.

I could get the std. dev. of the whole data set,

```
data <- read.csv("Berkshire.csv")
sd1 <-sd(data$BRKRet, na.rm = TRUE) #0.0675
mean<- mean(data$BRKRet, na.rm = TRUE) #0.0189
```

but I'm not sure how to find the std. dev. of a dataset over a certain time period. For example, from Nov. 17, 2010 ~ Nov.16, 2020.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I eventually came up with a lame way to solve this homework problem but I still wonder what's the proper solution to this question. (I deleted the data except for the certain time period and ran my code above.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do that if your dataset contains a column encoding the date (see `Dates` and related info) that you can filter by.
See below a simulated dataset of such type.

```
df <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(4000, mean = 0, sd = 1+(1:4000)/1000), "d" = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 4000))
```

Then it should be pretty standard:

```
# sd of x over the whole dataset
sd(df$x)
#[1] 3.121845

# define a logical vector identifying the dates of interest
interval <- (df$d >= as.Date("2010-11-17")) & (df$d <= as.Date("2020-11-16"))

# calculate the sd over the dates of interest only
sd(df[interval,]$x)
#[1] 3.227157

# display it as a plot
plot(x ~ d, df, col = ifelse(interval,2,1))
```

Only, make sure you check what your date format is, as that might depend on your system. Like:

```
Sys.Date()
[1] "2021-03-21"
```

This shows that my system expresses the date as "year-month-day". That's the format I used for the filtering in `as.Date` conversions.
[Note: there might be clever ways to use other formats].

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I'm quite sure it's helpful but I still got an error message related to data frame. I feel lost at this point.. The data is something like: [data](https://imgur.com/GHFBz45); the error is: [error](https://imgur.com/Zo7qkeg). Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: How I did to get the stdev for the whole data set: [link](https://imgur.com/qXsXhNl)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I must have been overthinking. For this problem, the solution could be:

```
# Loading the csv file
mydata <- read.csv('Berkshire.csv')
# Selecting the data from 30th Nov 1976 to 31st Dec 2005 after inspecting the data
newdata <- mydata[1:350, ]
# Selecting the return on the aggregate stock market for calculating standard deviation
returnOnStocks = newdata[, 2]
# Calculating the Standar Deviation and converting that into percentage
standard_deviation = sd(returnOnStocks, na.rm = TRUE) * 100
# Printing the Standard Deviation
print(standard_deviation)
```